# Vertical Collapsible Panel - Displayed collapsed on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onload

How would I be able to have a `<div>` already collapsed when the page loads?

I have a [JS Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqWk2/771/) with what I've got so far.

---

HTML

```
<button id="aa">Toggle it up</button>

<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

CSS

```
div { 
    background:#0F0; 
    margin:3px; 
    width:600px; 
    height:600px; 
    float:right;
}
div.test { 
    background:#345; 
    width:5px;
}
#aa {width: 100px; 
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 10 
    float: right;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#aa").click(function () {
    $("div").animate({width: 'toggle'});;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#test{
  display:none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RqWk2/773/)

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

Hide the div using css

```css
#test{
  display:none;
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/L5DTV/)</kbd>

---

**jQuery**

```css
$('#test').hide();
```

---

**JavaScript**

```css
document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
```